# Coefficient matrix for an implicit scheme for heat equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, python

I have a problem where I have 1D filament that is heated in one end (x=0) at a temperature T=210C (this is the first non-homogenous BC), and the other end (x=L) we have two boundary conditions: T(x=L)=25C and there is no flux (Neumann BC) at this point where dT(x=L)/dx=0.

I am using the implicit Euler scheme in time and central difference in space to solve the !D heat equation and model this system. However, looking at the solution I can see that the coefficient matrix of this scheme is given by:
[image]
[image]
Which has been confusing me a lot! Could you please shed some light on why the matrix looks like this. Specifically speaking, why A(0,0) = A(N,N) = 1 instead of -2, and why A(0,1)=0, and lastly why A(N-1)=A(N-2)=-1!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem appears to be over-posed. You can't have two boundary conditions at one end of a 2-point boundary value problem. So you can only implement  wither $\mathrm dT/\mathrm dx = 0$ or $T=T_L$, but not both.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK, suppose we implement the zero gradient boundary condition only, how the matrix becomes as shown above?

Comment: I've responded with an answer below. There is no need to use a full matrix.

Comment: To specifically answer your question about why $a_{00}=1$ and not $-2$, this comes from the Dirichlet boundary condition and is an imposed constraint. It does not come from the PDE. Similarly the Neumann BC at $x=L$ comes from a backward finite difference, not the discretised PDE.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that the finite difference scheme

$$
\Bigl[\frac{\Delta x^2}{\alpha\Delta t}+2\Bigr]T_i^n-[1]T_{i+1}^n-[1]T_{i-1}^n=\Bigl[\frac{\Delta x^2}{\alpha\Delta t}\Bigr]T_i^{n-1}
$$

applied to all interior points $i=2 \cdots N-1$ can be represented as

$$a_iT_i^n + b_iT_{i+1}^n + c_iT_{i-1}^n=d_i$$

where $$a_i = \Bigl[\frac{\Delta x^2}{\alpha\Delta t}+2\Bigr]$$

$$b_i = c_i =-1$$

and $$d_i = \Bigl[\frac{\Delta x^2}{\alpha\Delta t}\Bigr]T_i^{n-1}$$

which represents a tri-diagonal matrix, so that there is no need for the storage of a full matrix.

The boundary conditions are implemented as

$$
a_1 = 1,\hspace{0.5 in}b_1=0,\hspace{0.5 in}c_1=0,\hspace{0.5 in}d_1=T_0
$$

and using a simple backward finite-difference for the Neuman condition at $x=L$, ($i=N$), we have

$$
a_N = 1,\hspace{0.5 in}b_N=0,\hspace{0.5 in}c_N=-1,\hspace{0.5 in}d_N=0
$$

So you start with the initial condition $T_i^0 = T(x)$ at all nodes and then solve the tri-diagonal system at each time step, and then update the temperatures until the desired time interval has been simulated.

The tri-diagonal system can be very efficiently solved with the Tri-Diagonal Matrix Algorithm (TDMA or Thomas) Algorithm which is described at

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm

I wrote the section in the wiki page above that also has the code for solving a TDMA so feel free to ask me if anything isn't clear.

Hope this helps. Note that my indexing runs from $1$ to $N$, but can just as easily be implemented from $0$ to $N$.

Comment: Many thanks fro your detailed comment. I still, though, can't understand why the boundary conditions are implemented in a way that a(0,0)=a(N,N)=1. What does that physically mean?

Comment: $a(0,0)=1$ together with $(a0,1)=0$ is how you implement the Dirichlet BC at $x=0$. At the boundary, the PDE is overridden with this condition.

Comment: Likewise at $x=L$, the Neumann condition can be implemented with a first order accurate backward difference which boils down to stipulating that $T(N)=T(N-1)$. Accordingly, we have $-a(N,N-1)=A(N,N)=1$ with the right hand vector element equal to zero.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think I've got the idea now.

Comment: You’re Welcome.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! But it seems that the idea hasn't completely settled in my brain! I can understand that a(0,0)=1 instead of the value that resides on the diagonal element because we have a fixed boundary condition on the left at x=0. But why a(0,1) as well? what is the equation that we derived this result from? Also, We don't have a fixed boundary condition at x=L, we have a Neumann which means that T(N)=T(N-1) , but here T(N)=1 (instead of 2 because it is in the diagonal) and T(N-1)=-1 which doesn't equal to T(N)! Are there certain equations we are deriving these values from?

Comment: No worries. What seems to be the issue? By the way I just noticed and fixed a typo in my answer. It should be $c_N=-1$, not $c_N=1$

Comment: a(0,0)=1 because there is a fixed boundary condition at x=0, right? why a(0,1) =0? why a(N,N)=1, why a(N,N-1)=-1 although Neumann boundary condition states that a(N,N)=a(N,N-1). I believe if there are certain equations that we derived these values from, things get easier.

Comment: Correct. And at $x=L$, you have $a(N,N-1)=-1$ in addition to $a(N,N)=1$, but $a(N,N)=1$ is not for the same reason that $a(0,0)=1$.

Comment: Why at =, we have (,−1)=−1 in addition to (,)=1? and what is the reason behind a(N,N)=1?

Comment: a(0,1) refers to the influence of the node just inside the boundary. In a Dirichlet BC, this node has no influence on the BC, therefore it is zero. In the Neumann condition at $x=L$, the zero slope is implemented by making the temperature at $i=N$ equal to the temperature at $i=N-1$, therefore both coefficients have the same magnitude , but opposition in sign, owing to the template $a_i T_i +b_i T_{i+1}+c_i T_{i-1} = d_i$

Comment: You have to pose the BCs in the same template as used for the discretisation of the PDE itself.